# SSO/CAS intranet session to my Java EE portlet

Tags: spring, session, single-sign-on, portlet, cas

I develop a jsp/servlet application that will be a "portlet" on intranet and I want that the user stay connect to his intranet CAS session and retrieve session informations to use in my application (like login).

If the user is not connected to CAS, I want to redirect to.

I use Spring in my java connections to LDAP and maybe I can found SSO/CAS session in this framework.

If anyone has a suggestion please say me, it's an urgent project...

EDIT: My application will be "portlet", integrate on a Jahia website which need to connect to CAS to access it

Comment: hehe you see I've voted for your questions so now help me to resolve this ;)

Comment: Very difficult java2e for me, im noob.

Comment: Alor tu galere ou ta réussi a géré ton pb ? :)

Comment: @eouti : j'vais laisser mon tuteur réfléchir à la question pour l'instant ;)

Answer (score 1):

If this was a straight Servlet or JSP issue, I'd say that you should use Spring Security to handle the CAS integration (through `spring-security-cas-client.jar` as documented in the [SpringSec docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.pdf)).

However, you're using a Portlet framework which makes everything *much* more complex. You should check their documentation, as security is usually one of the things handled by the Portlet framework. (A quick scan of their [admin docs](http://www.jahia.org/files/content/sites/JahiaOrg/files/jahiapedia/JahiaEEv6AdminGuide_EN_v3_Feb10.pdf) isn't helpful; it seems entirely focused on password management rather than delegating it to a separate specialist service like CAS.)

Comment: FWIW, this is the first I'd ever heard of Jahia…

Comment: I use Jahia to portlet container